# Streaming WebM on unsupported platforms (Safari, IE, etc)

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, transcoding

I'd like to stream WebM videos to browsers that don't support it (like Safari/IE). I have no problem in converting the video to a supportable format (like MP4), but the encoding should be on-demand, that is, the server should stream the MP4 content while it's being converted from Web (WebM -> MP4). I've seen a few solutions like [Dash](http://wiki.webmproject.org/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-playback-adaptive-webm-using-dash) and [Stream-M](https://github.com/vbence/stream-m), but all these seem to do it the other way around (MP4 -> WebM). Is there a solution that already exists for my problem? Or do I need to build my own hack? And also is this solution the only way to stream WebM content onto Safari/IE?